# Wireless device "not available" after disconnecting from network

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

After successfully connecting to my saved home network using NetworkManager, then disconnecting, I can no longer connect despite my wireless interface apparently being available.

## System info

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.152-1 (2020-10-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## networking.service before connecting

```
$ sudo systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2020-11-26 15:54:47 GMT; 28s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 2594 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2594 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

## Successfully connect to saved connection

```
$ nmcli con up home5
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1)
```

## Verify connection

```
$ nmcli con
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
home5               777ade6c-785a-47b3-8618-bbd9863bcf4f  wifi      wlp3s0 
guest               ef86fb9d-e6c6-4a40-9c66-3a70c011bf80  wifi      --     
home2               522dee75-b24e-4f9f-a8b8-e5a2d06dbd23  wifi      --     
Wired connection 1  1ff7e76d-a4e4-3795-9550-d084cb3cb9ff  ethernet  --
```

```
$ nmcli -p device show wlp3s0
===============================================================================
                            Device details (wlp3s0)
===============================================================================
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     home5
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.107/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = XXX.XXX.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = XXX.XXX.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = XXX.X.XXX.179/32, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 0
IP4.DNS[1]:                             84.200.69.80
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/XX
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Disconnect

```
$ nmcli con down home5
Connection 'home5' successfully deactivated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1)
```

```
$ sudo dmesg
[  364.051145] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  425.375721] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  426.574527] wlp3s0: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[  426.582082] wlp3s0: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[  426.583540] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  426.587829] wlp3s0: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[  426.588766] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=3)
[  426.590296] wlp3s0: associated
[  426.634436] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[  886.307938] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  886.324494] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  889.353844] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  889.743616] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[  889.957723] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
```

## Attempt reconnection

```
$ nmcli con up home5
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device wlp3s0 not available because device is not available).
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some further research for similar issues and noticed **wicd** is known to interfere with NetworkManager. I had wicd uninstalled as I used to use it. However, **wicd-gtk** and **wicd-daemon** were still hanging around.

After removing 'wicd*' completely by running the following, I was able to connect/disconnect/reconnect to my network as expected using nmcli.

```
sudo dpkg -r wicd-gtk && sudo dpkg -P wicd-gtk
sudo dpkg -r wicd-daemon && sudo dpkg -P wicd-daemon
```